# Why is it not enough to reference the Bootstrap css and js to use Bootstrap classes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-web-api

I'm referencing bootstrap css and js (as well as jQuery js) in some dynamically-generated HTML,  and then applying a bootstrap class to an h1 element, but it isn't altering the appearance of said h1 text. I'm generating the key (for this question) part of the HTML with this code:

```
        private string GetBeginningHTML()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<html>");
            builder.Append("<head>");
            builder.Append("<title>");
            string availableRpts = string.Format("Available Reports For {0}", _unit);
            builder.Append(availableRpts);
            builder.Append("</title>");
            builder.Append("</head>");
            builder.Append("<body>");

            builder.AppendFormat("<link href='{0}' rel='stylesheet' />",     
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
"~/Content/bootstrap.min.css"));
            builder.AppendFormat("<script src='{0}'></script>",        
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
"~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"));
            builder.AppendFormat("<script src='{0}'></script>",     
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(
"~/Scripts/jquery-
1.10.2.min.js"));

            // Add Header rows
            builder.Append("<div class=\"jumbotron\">"); 
            builder.Append(String.Format("<h1>Available Reports for {0}
</h1>", _unit.ToUpper

()));
            builder.Append("</div>");

            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

...and from it, I get the following html returned:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Available Reports For GRAMPS</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href='C:\Projects\PlatypusWebReports\PlatypusWebReports\Content\bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='C:\Projects\PlatypusWebReports\PlatypusWebReports\Scripts\bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='C:\Projects\PlatypusWebReports\PlatypusWebReports\Scripts\jquery-
1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Available Reports for GRAMPS</h1>
</div>
```

...I then append other html to it; the page renders okay, but the jumbotron class is not being applied to the h1 text - the "Available Reports for ..." div has no special appearance.

Why is bootstrap's jumbotron class not being applied? I am referencing the bootstrap css and javascript, as well as the jQuery js file, so theoretically (ISTM) it should work.

I thought maybe the css and script references needed to precede the opening "body" tag, but moving the css and script references above the body tag makes no difference.

Comment: You can't reference resources from disk.  You need to use URLs from the server.

Comment: You can reference resources from disk, but not like that. You should use the file:// method (note that \ need to be changed to /) like so: `file:///C:/Projects/ ...` Also css should be within the head element. (Note that for file:// to work, the files must be on the machine that the web browser is running on, so this won't work if your webserver and those files are on a separate machine)

Comment: You may want to get the css and js from a CDN instead of using local files. See https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: @BenHolness, make that an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to reference the bootstrap and jquery CSS and JS from a CDN rather than a local file.

See https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and https://code.jquery.com/ for links to the latest versions.

Also note that the CSS should be within the head element

Answer (score 0):

Using Ben Holness' suggestion, this is what I did (it works):

```
. . .
builder.Append("</title>");
builder.Append("<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />");
builder.Append("<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>");
builder.Append("<script src=\"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js\" integrity=\"sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\"></script>");
builder.Append("</head>");
. . .
```